# In Android, How to kill or stop the sound played by an AudioTrack object that is started by an external class?

Tags: android, audio, cardreader, xamarin.android

I'm currently using a 3rd party library in a Mono for Android project. This library is used for connecting a card reader device (IDTech Unimag Reader) into the headphones jack. While I'am using the application with the device connected everything works great, however when I send the application to the background and unplug the reader device and plug my headphones an annoying sound is played, and until I kill the process, the sound stops. The bad news is that the card reader library doesn't expose a method to stop this sound.  Is it possible to stop this sound programatically without having to kill the process?

Comment: Check the logs to see if a `HEADSET_PLUG` intent is broadcast when you detach the card reader device. If it is and the library ignores it then it sounds like a bug in the library that you should report to the 3rd party vendor. Have you read the documentation for the library to see if there's any mention of stopping the "audio" output?

Comment: The documentation only mentions a .release() method that should free the resources used by the card reader. Despite of using it, is not stopping that sound. Also I have analized a demo code that comes with the library and this demo has an explicit "Exit" button that calls Android.OS.Process.KillProcess, maybe this could be the only way to stop it, but that solution would be the last one I would use as my last option